# How would I pass this Coldfusion url param?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

What is the correct syntax to pass a url param to the following:

```
var myInbox = "/test/SecComm/ajax_inboxResults.cfm?folderID="+url.folderID;
      $.post(myInbox,function(data){
          $("#messageList").html(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do it that way.  You can also pass a `data` parameter according to the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Note that `post` is shorthand for `ajax` which are the docs I linked.

So just add

```
data: {
   folderID: <cfoutput>#url.folderId#</cfoutput>
}
```

into your post invocation, and remove the `?folderID....` from your query string.  For your case it doesn't really matter, but the more params you want to pass, the cleaner using `data` will be.

Comment: I prefer this answer, but it must use bittersweetryan's suggestion of wrapping the url.folderId variable in # symbols, as there is an implied assumption you are in the middle of a JavaScript block of code, but injecting server-side CF variables--and additionally, must be wrapped in CFOUTPUT.

Comment: That was my first thought (to wrap everyting in a CFOUTPUT tag) but thought there was another way to do this.  Thank you very much for your responses.  Kerrie

Answer (score 2):

url.folderID is a ColdFusion parameter, not a JavaScript one. If this code is in your .cfm file just surround it with #'s

```
var myInbox = "/test/SecComm/ajax_inboxResults.cfm?folderID="+#url.folderID#;
```